# python3 Decimal calculation acts differently when the value is enclosed within quotes

Tags: python

Decimal variables in python, is giving different result with arithmetic operations, depending on whether the number was enclosed in quotes  when the value was assigned.

```
>>> x = Decimal(5.36)
>>> y = Decimal(10.56)
>>> x * y
Decimal('56.60160000000000604245542490')

>>> x = Decimal('5.36')
>>> y = Decimal('10.56')
>>> x * y
Decimal('56.6016')
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input value in the first case is a pair of floats, which by definition are imprecise. See also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

In the second case, the strings can be converted directly to the `Decimal` internal representation, which is precise.

You can verify this for yourself:

```py
>>> x = Decimal(5.36)
>>> print(x)
5.36000000000000031974423109204508364200592041015625
>>> y = Decimal(10.56)
>>> print(y)
10.5600000000000004973799150320701301097869873046875
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/kieftu